# Merge two repositories (FreeSwitch)

Tags: git, github, merge, freeswitch

I have a question regarding merging 2 repositories. Once upon a time I was doing some FreeSwitch enhancements so I forker their repository and worked on that. Now I want to merge their latest changes into mine repository, but they moved it out of github to https://stash.freeswitch.org/scm/fs/freeswitch.git. So my question is - is there an easy way of merging their latest changes to my fork? I found some suggestion here: http://blog.caplin.com/2013/09/18/merging-two-git-repositories/ but I wonder if there is better way of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually a lot simpler. You don't need to merge two git repositories with separate roots, you only have to attach your repo to an additional remote.

You just need to run (depending on whether you already have a second remote for upstream or not)

```
git remote add upstream https://stash.freeswitch.org/scm/fs/freeswitch.git
git remote set-url upstream https://stash.freeswitch.org/scm/fs/freeswitch.git
```

then `git fetch upstream`, followed by either `git merge upstream/master` or `git rebase upstream/master` depending on whether you (or upstream) want linear history or not.